# An alternative to "while" for making repeated requests to a server

Tags: scala, while-loop, future

I have a function  which should return a result either from the db or a server. But the server might fail and return nothing and in that case I need to repeat the server request until it returns the result:

```
def getToken() = 
  getTokenFromDb orElse getTokenFromServer() map { t =>
    saveTokenToDb(t)
    t
  }
```

What is a sensible solution for repetitive requests to `getTokenFromServer()` until I get a good response from it except using `while` loop?  Of maybe using `while` is a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

This may sound insane, but you could create a stream of infinite server-requests, and then use "takeWhile + isDefined" :) I think that may actually be quite easy to implement. If I get to my code-machine, I'll whip something up :)

Comment: I realize now, that is basically the suggestion that is already there (in a better form, really).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as you have no specific requirements on how many attempts you want it to try the server, just use recursion. This is in fact almost the same as while loop :) but in more functional style.
So make the getTokenFromServer() recursive.
But do not forget about the tail-recursion, i.e. the recursive call to the getTokenFromServer() from within itself must be a last code statement in it's code. That way you will not get any troubles with stack overflowing.